# Docker on WSL2: Volumes always anonymously

Tags: docker, docker-volume, wsl-2

Anybody have an idea why the following is not true anymore?
I have W10 20H2, Docker V 20.10.2

And WSL 2 is enabled and works.

Fact docker volume create blah
creates a folder in
file://///wsl$/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data/community/docker/volumes/blah

when I want to USE that folder using the -v volume argument
say
docker container run -d -p 80:80 myimage -v blah:/app/app_data/media

I get an anonymous volume say.
file://///wsl$/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data/community/docker/volumes/8185693afeacbf8d35805fb3df98635da122a088f39bd41bb58252931d1241f0/

*no matter* what I try, use --mount instead of -v the randomly generated folders remain making it useless for my purpose!
(the same when I create from within ubuntu on Windows itself)

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: The `-v` option needs to be _before_ `myimage`; otherwise it's interpreted as the command to run.  You're probably getting the anonymous volume because your Dockerfile declares a `VOLUME`.

Comment: Wow, thanks a mile.